# Can't set shared Excel add-in group image

Tags: c#, xml, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

I've got two addins and they are using the same group. For demonstration purposes I'll add an example from the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)#how-do-i-create-two-add-ins-that-add-items-to-the-same-group-or-tab).

First add-in:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" xmlns:x="myNameSpace">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group idQ="x:Contoso" label="Contoso">
          <button id="C1" label="Contoso Button 1" size="large" 
                  imageMso="FileSave" onAction="c_action1" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Second add-in:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" xmlns:x="myNameSpace">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group idQ="x:Contoso" label="Contoso">
          <button id="C2" label="Contoso Button 2" size="large" 
                  imageMso="FileSave" onAction="c_action2" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

How do I set an image for the group? Is it even possible?

What I've tried so far (and did not provide any results):

Adding a callback for the getImage attribute:

```
<group idQ="x:Contoso" label="Contoso" getImage="grp_GetImage">
```

Callback:

```
public Bitmap grp_GetImage(IRibbonControl control) => Icons.GroupIcon;
```

I also tried adding a callback for the loadImage attribute:

```
<customUI ... xmlns:x="myNameSpace" loadImage="loadGroupImage">
...
  <group ... image="groupImage">
    ...
  </group>
  ...
</customUI>
```

Callback:

```
public Bitmap LoadRibbonGroupImage(string imageName)
{
    return Icons.GroupIcon;
}
```

Important thing to note: The callbacks were not executed in any of these attempts. (When I tried the same approaches with an element that did not have an idQ, the callbacks were executed properly.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Image instead of ImageMso.

Comment: I tried using image as described in the last two code snippets, but it didn't work. The imageMso part is related to the group's buttons, it is not relevant.

Comment: There are three pages to the documentation.  You are looking at page 3.  See page 1 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)#loading-images

Comment: And how does the example on page 1 differ from my second approach to solving this problem? The "I also tried adding a callback for the loadImage attribute" part of the question.

Comment: The link is using image and you are using imageMso.

Comment: Where am I using imageMso? Besides the buttons, and they are _example_ buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using.  Just at top of this posting you have First/Second add-in that shows imageMso.  You said later "I also tried" which has image, but not sure what you tried is different than page 1.